# Separating multiple results onto different lines

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, office365

I have the following PowerShell script in which I can run to get a good mixed report from Office 365.

```
$Results = @()
$MailboxUsers = get-mailbox -resultsize unlimited
$Statistics = $MailboxUsers | Get-MailboxStatistics | select *
$Licenses = Get-MsolUser | select *
$Permissions = $MailboxUsers | Get-MailboxPermission | select *

foreach($user in $mailboxusers)
{
$UPN = $user.userprincipalname

      $Properties = @{
      Name = $user.name
      UPN = $UPN
      Alias = $user.alias
      RecipientTypeDetails = $user.RecipientTypeDetails
      Identity = ($Permissions | where {$_.Identity -eq ($user).DisplayName}).Identity
      User = ($Permissions | where {$_.Identity -eq ($user).DisplayName}).User
      AccessRights = ($Permissions | where {$_.Identity -eq ($user).DisplayName}).AccessRights
      IsInherited = ($Permissions | where {$_.Identity -eq ($user).DisplayName}).IsInherited
      Deny = ($Permissions | where {$_.Identity -eq ($user).DisplayName}).Deny
      IsLicensed = ($Licenses | where {$_.UserPrincipalName -eq ($user).UserPrincipalName}).IsLicensed
      TotalItemSize = ($Statistics | where {$_.DisplayName -eq ($user).DisplayName}).TotalItemSize
      ItemCount = ($Statistics | where {$_.DisplayName -eq ($user).DisplayName}).ItemCount
      License = ($Licenses | where {$_.UserPrincipalName -eq ($user).UserPrincipalName}).Licenses.AccountSkuId
      }
$Results += New-Object psobject -Property $properties
}

$results | sort name | fl
```

However, when I run this, 5 objects **Identity**, **User**, **AccessRights**, **IsInherited** and **Deny** all show multiple results mixed into the same output.

Even if I change the last line to this:

```
$results | sort name | Out-GridView
```

This also shows the same 5 objects **Identity**, **User**, **AccessRights**, **IsInherited** and **Deny** all bunched together.

What I am looking for is to separate the 5 objects **Identity**, **User**, **AccessRights**, **IsInherited** and **Deny** onto different lines, and for the rest of the objects, just to repeat e.g. **Name**, **UPN**, **License**, **RecipientTypeDetails**, **TotalItemSize**, **Alias**, **IsLicensed** and **ItemCount** would be repeated beside each result in the 5 objects **Identity**, **User**, **AccessRights**, **IsInherited** and **Deny**.

This way I can do more things with the output, put it into Excel for example  and massage the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use note properties individually defined like below to build your output results, It works for me and can easily be exported to what ever format you need from here. Check that i got all the properties and in the right order.

```
foreach($user in $mailboxusers)
{
$UPN = $user.userprincipalname

$match = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
$match | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $user.name
$match | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "UPN" -Value $UPN
$match | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "Alias" -Value $user.alias
$match | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "RecipientTypeDetails" -Value $user.RecipientTypeDetails
$match | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "Identity" -Value ($Permissions | where {$_.Identity -eq ($user).DisplayName}).Identity
$match | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "User" -Value ($Permissions | where {$_.Identity -eq ($user).DisplayName}).User
$match | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "AccessRights" -Value ($Permissions | where {$_.Identity -eq ($user).DisplayName}).AccessRights
$match | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "IsInherited" -Value ($Permissions | where {$_.Identity -eq ($user).DisplayName}).IsInherited
$match | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "Deny" -Value ($Permissions | where {$_.Identity -eq ($user).DisplayName}).Deny
$match | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "IsLicensed" -Value ($Licenses | where {$_.UserPrincipalName -eq ($user).UserPrincipalName}).IsLicensed
$match | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "TotalItemSize" -Value ($Statistics | where {$_.DisplayName -eq ($user).DisplayName}).TotalItemSize
$match | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "ItemCount" -Value ($Statistics | where {$_.DisplayName -eq ($user).DisplayName}).ItemCount
$match | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "License" -Value ($Licenses | where {$_.UserPrincipalName -eq ($user).UserPrincipalName}).Licenses.AccountSkuId

$Results += $match
}
```